# Having Matlab randomly choose a number from a select few that I designate

Tags: matlab

sorry if this is relatively simple, but I'm new to Matlab and trying to learn the ropes. What I'm asking is simply the following. I was a function that will randomly choose a number with the only options for it to choose from being `-3,-1,1, and 1`. What I was trying to do was something like this below.

```
clear;
N=10e5;
B=randint(1,N,[-3 || -1 || 1 || 3]);
Bmean=sum(B)/N
Bvar=sum((B-Bmean).^2)/(N-1)
```

but obviously I can't set up a range that way.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
N = 10; I assume N is sample size you want.
B = datasample([-3,-1,1, 1], N);
B =
    -3     1     1     1     1     1    -1     1    -3     1
```

[datasample](http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/stats/datasample.html) is from statistical toolbox. Not sure you have it or not.

Comment: that datasample function is EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks!

Now I just need to figure out how to make it display the probability of each possible outcome.

Comment: @Dom Cool. So accepting the answer would be most appreciated :-)

Answer (score 3):

Why not only generate random index:

```
A = [-3 -1 1 3];
idx = randint(1, N, numel(A)) + 1;
B = A(idx);
```

Fortunately, this is builtin function and does not require extra toolbox.